# Oracle SQL, round greater than 'half' only

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to round 'half down' for a number and keep the (.5), for example:

if number = (9115.7 ) then (9116)

if number = (9115.5 ) then (9115.5)

if number = (9115.3 ) then (9115)

Comment: What if a number is 9115,51111  or 9115.599999 or  9115.5555555555555 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could rewrite own rounding logic using case expression:

```
CREATE TABLE t
AS
SELECT 9115.7 AS col FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 9115.5 AS col FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 9115.3 AS col FROM dual;

SELECT col, CASE WHEN MOD(ABS(col),1) = 0.5 THEN col ELSE ROUND(col) END
FROM t;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bbab55ecec0ed475cb8787e1e9292d7d)**

Output:

```
+---------+---------+
|  COL    | ROUNDED |
+---------+---------+
| 9115.7  |    9116 |
| 9115.5  |  9115.5 |
| 9115.3  |    9115 |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: @forpas Yes, that is a more concise approach than https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=56e14e9ffda239f67271117d4ad597fb

Comment: Problem though... in Oracle (and in some other languages) `mod()` does not behave as it should, based on the mathematical definition of `mod`. Namely, `mod(-3.5, 1)` is -0.5, not 0.5. The query can be modified easily to fix this.

Comment: @mathguy Sure, I added `ABS` function to handle it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bbab55ecec0ed475cb8787e1e9292d7d